# select the top 2 users by country based on the users last login date

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to get a list of the top 2 accounts that by country. The users with the last two login dates from each country is the criteria that is used to determine the top 2 accounts. That is, the object is to achieve the last 2 last 2 users from each country with the max date.

```
--------------
 accountsTable
---------------------------------------
id  last_login_date         country_id
1   2016-07-13 13:52:10         3
2   2016-03-30 10:11:18         3
3   2016-03-30 10:11:18         1
4   2017-01-13 22:34:20         2
5   2017-04-22 12:25:04         2
6   2017-04-24 15:12:00         1
7   2017-05-18 10:16:30         4
8   2017-10-04 23:21:12         4
9   2017-10-10 00:54:55         2
10  2017-10-13 14:28:34         2
11  2017-06-18 10:16:30         4
---------------------------------------


---------------
countriesTable
--------------------------
country_id      country
--------------------------
1               UK
2               France 
3               Germany
4               Japan
5               Brazil
6               Chile
7               Mexico
--------------------------


--------------
Desired Output
------------------------------------------------
country     country_id      last_login_date
------------------------------------------------
UK          1               2017-04-24 15:12:00 
UK          1               2016-03-30 10:11:18     
France      2               2017-10-13 14:28:34
France      2               2017-10-10 00:54:55
Germany     3               2016-03-30 10:11:18
Germany     3               2016-07-13 13:52:10
Japan       4               2017-05-18 10:16:30
Japan       4               2017-10-04 23:21:12
------------------------------------------------

select country, countriesTable.country_id, last_login_date
from countriesTable
inner join accountsTable
on countriesTable.country_id = accountsTable.country_id
group by (country)
order by last_login_date
limit 2
```

Table structure for countriesTable.

```
create table countriesTable(
    country_id int primary key,
    country varchar(20)
);
```

Insert for the countriesTable.

```
insert into countriesTable values (1, 'UK');
insert into countriesTable values (2, 'France');
insert into countriesTable values (3, 'Germany');
insert into countriesTable values (4, 'Japan');
insert into countriesTable values (5, 'Brazil');
insert into countriesTable values (6, 'Chile');
insert into countriesTable values (7, 'Mexico');
```

Table structure for accountsTable.

```
create table accountsTable(
    id int primary key,
    last_login_date timestamp, 
    country_id int
);
```

Inserts for accountsTable.

```
insert into accountsTable values(1, '2016-07-13 13:52:10', 3);
insert into accountsTable values(2, '2016-03-30 10:11:18', 3);
insert into accountsTable values(3, '2016-03-30 10:11:18', 1);
insert into accountsTable values(4, '2017-01-13 22:34:20', 2);
insert into accountsTable values(5, '2017-04-22 12:25:04', 2);
insert into accountsTable values(6, '2017-04-24 15:12:00', 1);
insert into accountsTable values(7, '2017-05-18 10:16:30', 4);
insert into accountsTable values(8, '2017-10-04 23:21:12', 4);
insert into accountsTable values(9, '2017-10-10 00:54:55', 2);
insert into accountsTable values(10, '2017-10-13 14:28:34',2);
insert into accountsTable values(11, '2017-06-18 10:16:30', 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query should work:

```
select countriesTable.country, countriesTable.country_id, at_.last_login_date
from countriesTable
inner join accountsTable at_
on countriesTable.country_id = at_.country_id
where (select count(*)
       from accountsTable at2
       where at_.country_id = at2.country_id
       and at2.last_login_date>=at_.last_login_date
      )<=2
order by at_.country_id
```

Comment: I am trying to adjust your solution to make it work. But there are not fields in the accountsTable by the  name last_login_date

Comment: It's there in your question and your query too

Comment: That correct. That is my mistake it is in the table.

Comment: No its not working. I am getting an error. Error code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; ...

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'at2.last_login_date>=at.last_login_date)<=2 order by last_login_date' at line 7 0.000 sec

Comment: My bad...Just add the `where` clause before `at2.last_login_date...`. I've edited my answer too

Comment: This solution is not working. No records are being returned when I execute the query

Comment: Rather, It is not generating the desired result

Comment: It works now what was the issue that was causing it not to work. Was it the change of the order by to at_.country_id that made it work.

Comment: I forgot to compare the `country_id` of inner query with the `country_id` of outer query.

Comment: No`order by` has nothing to do with the logic. It is just used to arrange/sort  the output based on given column.